# jQuery UI Tooltip - delaying Ajax request

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm performing an ajax request for my tooltip, and want a delay before the tooltip is displayed.
The show option is providing a delay for displaying the tooltip, but I also want to delay the ajax request (so it doesn't trigger multiple times when quickly moving the mouse over a group of elements).

I managed to achieve something like that using setTimeout, but using it every time I need a tooltip seems like an overkill. Are there built in options where a delay takes place before the content function is fired?

```
var tooltipTimeoutID = null;
$("div#Main").tooltip ({
     items: "div.Row"
     content: function(callback) {
          tooltipTimeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
              callback(myAjaxRequest());
          }, 300)'
     }),
     show: { delay: 400 },
     close: function(evt, ui) {
         clearTimeout(tooltipTimeoutID);
     }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with using SetTimeout, just make sure you're binding it to a variable (as you're already doing) and cancel it whenever the ajax request isn't needed anymore, such as mouseout or another tooltip being called

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented way to delay calling function in content. I think if you just first try to get the current content of tooltip if it's already filled avoid calling ajax function again. If that's an option for you.

```
// get current content of tooltip

var content = $("div#Main").tooltip( "option", "content" );
if(content.length > 0)
{
return callback(content);

}else //call the ajax function
{
tooltipTimeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
              callback(myAjaxRequest());
          }, 300);
}
```